# Nested array with mat-table

Tags: angular, mat-table

I have a nested array and I want to display this with mat-table.

In the array are two different modules "Flex" with several positions that are to be displayed in a table.

Since there are two "Flex" modules in the array, two tables should also be displayed like this example:

**FLEX**

| Position | ID | Menge | Bezeichnung | BP_Gesamt |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | STZBH | 2 | Xpress weiss | 1998,00 |
| 2 | STZBG | 5 | Xpress schwarz | 3998,00 |

**FLEX**

| Position | ID | Menge | Bezeichnung | BP_Gesamt |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | STZBH | 4 | Xpress weiss | 3996,00 |
| 2 | STZBG | 4 | Xpress schwarz | 3996,00 |

```
[
{
    "module": "Flex",
    "positionen": [
        {
            "Position": 0,
            "ID": {
                "id": "XLEW_1_2_2",
                "wert": "STZBH"
            },
            "Menge": {
                "id": "XLEW_1_2_5",
                "wert": "2"
            },
            "Bezeichnung": {
                "id": "XLEW_1_2_6",
                "wert": "Xpress weiss"
            },
            "BP_Gesamt": {
                "id": "XLEW_1_2_17",
                "wert": "1998,00"
            }
        },
        {
            "Position": 1,
            "ID": {
                "id": "XLEW_1_2_2",
                "wert": "STZBH"
            },
            "Menge": {
                "id": "XLEW_1_2_5",
                "wert": "5"
            },
            "Bezeichnung": {
                "id": "XLEW_1_2_6",
                "wert": "Xpress weiss"
            },
            "BP_Gesamt": {
                "id": "XLEW_1_2_17",
                "wert": "3998,00"
            }
        }
    ]
},
{
    "module": "Flex",
    "positionen": [
        {
            "Position": 0,
            "ID": {
                "id": "XLEW_1_2_2",
                "wert": "STZBH"
            },
            "Menge": {
                "id": "XLEW_1_2_5",
                "wert": "4"
            },
            "BP_Gesamt": {
                "id": "XLEW_1_2_17",
                "wert": "3996,00"
            }
        },
        {
            "Position": 1,
            "ID": {
                "id": "XLEW_1_2_2",
                "wert": "STZBG"
            },
            "Menge": {
                "id": "XLEW_1_2_5",
                "wert": "4"
            },
            "Bezeichnung": {
                "id": "XLEW_1_2_6",
                "wert": "Xpress schwarz"
            },
            "BP_Gesamt": {
                "id": "XLEW_1_2_17",
                "wert": "3996,00"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

]

I'm new to Angular and mat-table and couldn't find a solution for my problem.

Can someone help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install underscore.js in your project and then you can use this code

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let td of table_data">
<h1>{{td.name}}</h1>
<table mat-table [dataSource]="td.data" class="mat-elevation-z8">
    <ng-container [matColumnDef]="column" *ngFor="let column of td.header">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> {{column}} </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element[column]}} </td>
    </ng-container>

    <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="td.header"></tr>
    <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: td.header;"></tr>
</table>
```

```
parseData(inputArray: any[]) {
    const returnArray = [];
    for (const data of inputArray) {
        const new_obj = { name: "", header: [], data: [] };
        const arr = [];
        new_obj["data"] = [];
        new_obj["name"] = data.module;
        for (const d of data.positionen) {
            const keys = Object.keys(d);
            const obj: any = {};
            for (const k of keys) {
                if (k === "Position") {
                    obj[k] = d[k];
                } else {
                    obj[k] = d[k].wert;
                }
            }
            new_obj["data"].push(obj);
            arr.push(keys);
        }
        new_obj["header"] = _.uniq(_.flatten(arr));
        returnArray.push(new_obj);
    }

    return returnArray;
}

ngOnInit(): void {
    this.table_data = this.parseData(PASS_YOUR_DATA_HERE);
}
```

Comment: you are my man! Thank so much! Works perfect